# Reduce gap between series data in Bar Highchart

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I want to reduce space between bar chart series data. Below mentioned is the image which gives a clear picture :

[image]

Can anyone suggest the best approach to do it?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635],
            pointWidth: 22,
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947],
            pointWidth: 22
        }]

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fMdk3/5/

Answer (score 21):

The options you want to play with are pointPadding (padding between bars) and groupPadding (padding between seies).

e.g.

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.1,
        }
    },
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/BZzWQ/

Comment: Would be really grateful if you can update your approach here (http://jsfiddle.net/fMdk3/5/)

Comment: Updated with example jsfiddle.

Comment: If I keep pointWidth Fix as 22 and then try to achieve same thing it does not happen. Is there any limitation? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/BZzWQ/1/

Comment: By setting the div height so large, you are makeing the chart have a lot of wasted space. Try not setting the height, and adjust the groupPadding e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gnM2R/

Comment: I would have done it. But the data with which I am dealing is dynamic and it changes quite often. So I wanted a universal solution. Number of data series vary.

Comment: Its only way to control gaps between bars, as SteveP mentions.

Comment: Having same problem. Did you found any solution?